# Wordpress coinslider image gallery overlap

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress, gallery

I have a wordpress website which uses a premium theme http://www.inspiredxpressions.co.za/weddings/
The nivoslider used to work as expected but now there is an image that is improperly positioned. My css skills is a bit limited but everything i have tried regarding margins, padding and display seem be have no effect.

Comment: What's the name of the theme? If one can compare with a sample wp page with that theme, it might help.

Answer (score 0):

Add below css code to style.css and things will look good.

```
.slider.nivoSlider img{
    display:none;
}
```